# Unable to send file and object together in a post request from Angular to SpirngBoot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest

[image]

I am trying to send a image and data object and a string as seperate from angular to spring boot. But even after trying a lot of different combinations, I am unable to get a success result.

My angular code is:

```
createPost(post:Post, categoryId:number,file:File):Observable<any>{
const url = `${this.baseURL}/api/createPost`;
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('post', JSON.stringify(post));
formData.append('categoryId', categoryId.toString());
formData.append('file', file, file.name);
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
return this.http.post<Post>(url, formData, { headers: headers });
}
```

My backend is :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/createPost")

public ResponseEntity<PostDTO> createPost(@RequestBody PostDTO postDTO,
@RequestParam String categoryId,
@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,
@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) throws IOException {
Integer parsedCategoryId = Integer.parseInt(categoryId);
Integer userId = userService.getUserByUsername(userDetails.getUsername()).getId();
String fileName = fileService.uploadImage(path, file);
postDTO.setImageName(fileName);
PostDTO createdPost = postService.createPost(postDTO,userId,parsedCategoryId);
return new ResponseEntity<PostDTO>(createdPost, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

The current error is:
[org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryqr5s9jtX7gBNGFzh;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]

how can I change it?